# Generate unique pairwise combinations of a column values based on 2 others columns in a data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have tried a lot of things and I even searched for similar questions but couldn't find
solutions.

Suppose that we have a data.table in R:

```
ID = c("1","1","1","2","2")
Code = c("A","B","C","B","C")
N = c("3","3","3","2","2")
```

so basically, I want to have unique pairwise combinations for column "Code" based on "ID" and "N" columns.

Is there an R function to return the following?

```
ID = c("1","1","1","2")
Combinations = c("A.B","B.C","C.A","B.C")
N = c("3","3","3","2")
```

as I said before I have tried many things but if gives me a data.table which contains only the combinations however in my final result I need to have a column for ID and 2 others for combinations and N

Do you have an idea how to do it ?

Comment: Why do your input ID and N vectors have 5 elements but the result ID and N have only 4?

Comment: How exactly should `N` and `ID` affect `Combinations`?

Comment: because I need only unique combination which mean ("B.C" is the same as "C.B")

Answer (score 1):

You may use `combn` in `group_by` -

```
library(dplyr)

result <- df %>%
  group_by(ID, N) %>%
  summarise(Code = combn(Code, 2, paste0, collapse = '.'), .groups = 'drop')

result

#  ID    N     Code 
#  <chr> <chr> <chr>
#1 1     3     A.B  
#2 1     3     A.C  
#3 1     3     B.C  
#4 2     2     B.C
```

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(ID, Code, N)
```

Comment: The [tag:data.table]-variant of this is `DT[, .(Combinations = c(combn(Code, 2, FUN = paste0, collapse = "."))), by = .(ID, N)]`. (The `c(.)` wrapper is because `combn` returns an `array`; `dplyr` sees one of the dims is 1 and collapses it, but `data.table` needs it to be explicitly a vector or `list`.)